# Windows Terminal useAcrylic property does not work

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

I have set property `"useAcrylic"` as `true`, but it doesn't work.
It's set in settings.json like

```
"defaults": {
            "acrylicOpacity": 0.4,
            "colorScheme" : "Frost",
            "useAcrylic": true
}
```

Windows version: **Windows 10 pro 20H2**
[Windows Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/308Pe.png) version: 1.7.1033.0

Comment: `"defaults":
        {
            "backgroundImage": "[pathToJpg]",
            "backgroundImageOpacity": 0.25,
            "colorScheme": "Elementary",
            "fontSize": 10,
            "useAcrylic": true,
            "acrylicOpacity": 0.8
        }`
Works fine for me, even if I delete background image. Do you have transparency effects enabled on your machine?

Comment: It seems that power saving mode disabled transparent effects. Problem solved! Thanks!@GrzegorzOchlik

Answer (score 3):

You have to change your appearance settings. Go to Settings > Personalisation > Transparency Effects and turn on this option.

I use windows 11 but works the same for windows 10.

Screenshot of the settings

[image: 1]